# SAX Parsing in Java

Tags: java, sax

I must parse an XML from URL in Java with SAX parser. I didn't find an example on the internet about this topic. All of them are reading an XML from local. Is there an example that xml has nested tags and parsing from url in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this example java snippet

```
        String webServiceURL="web service url or document url here";
        URL geoLocationDetailXMLURL = new URL(webServiceURL);
        URLConnection geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection = geoLocationDetailXMLURL.openConnection();
        geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(120000);
        geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.setReadTimeout(120000);
        BufferedReader geoLeocationDetails = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(geoLeocationDetails);
        saxParser.parse(inputSource, handler);
```

Comment: Thakns for this. How to take nested tags. Is there any example about this on your hand?

Comment: Please refer this URL:http://mohammed-technical.blogspot.in/2010/08/parsing-complex-nested-xml-with.html

Answer (score 1):

This should help
[SAX parser and a file from the nework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176082/sax-parser-and-a-file-from-the-nework)

The important line being

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

where sourceUrl is a string