# NullPointerException Java SAXParser

Tags: java, sax

I am parsing an XML with SAX. I wrote the codes like on tje internet examples that I have seen.I get url and then i parsed this. Here is my codes.

```
public class Urunler implements Serializable {

private String title;
private String description;

public Urunler(String title, String description) {
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
}

public Urunler() {
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String cevir() {
          StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
          sb.append("Title:" + getTitle());
          sb.append(", ");
          sb.append("Description:" + getDescription());
          sb.append(".");
          return sb.toString();
   }
}
```

Then I have  written a handler for parsing. It is below;

```
public class UrunlerHandler extends DefaultHandler{

private Urunler urunler;
private String temp;
private ArrayList<Urunler> urunlerList= new ArrayList<Urunler>();

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    temp = "";

    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){  
        urunler = new Urunler();
    }

}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    temp = new String(ch,start,length);
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
        urunlerList.add(urunler);
    }else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
        urunler.setTitle(temp);
    }else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
        urunler.setDescription(temp);
    }

}


public void readList(){
    Iterator<Urunler> it = urunlerList.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next().cevir());
    }
}
```

Then I have used in Main method like this;

```
     try {
        SAXParserFactory spfac = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();

        SAXParser sp = spfac.newSAXParser();

        UrunlerHandler handler = new UrunlerHandler();

        URL geoLocationDetailXMLURL = new URL(url);
        URLConnection geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection = geoLocationDetailXMLURL.openConnection();
        BufferedReader geoLeocationDetails = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(geoLocationDetailXMLURLConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(geoLeocationDetails);
        sp.parse(inputSource, handler);
        handler.readList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I cant't see en error. But it is giving error that NullPointerException.
Here is the url = "http://www.gold.com.tr/cok-satanlar-rss/54109/0"

Comment: Can you add your stacktrace ? where are you (what line) getting the exception ?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace? A line number where the null pointer is occuring? Edit: hivemind

Comment: }else if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
        urunler.setTitle(temp);   at this line.

Comment: That's two lines, which means either qName is null or urunler is null. Or the .setTitle method throws a null pointer if the argument is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sources you're using to learn SAX from are bad examples, see [the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) if you want to know how to do this the right way (or see the comment on [the accepted answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19399946/217324), which also points to a good tutorial).

But SAX is probably overkill for what you want here, XPath may be a simpler solution. It is more declarative and has less pitfalls.

Here's an example XML file, called foobar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
    <bar>hello</bar>
</foo>
```

I can use the XPath API that is part of the Java SDK to retrieve the element text for bar like this:

```
org.xml.sax.InputSource inputSource = new 
org.xml.sax.InputSource('c:/users/ndh/foobar.xml');
javax.xml.xpath.XPath xpath = 
    javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String text = (String)xpath.evaluate('/foo/bar/text()', 
    inputSource, javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.STRING);
```

The field text will contain "hello".

Answer (score 0):

Since urunler is null in your handler class, you should either be doing (A) a null check if it is allowed to be null or (B) defining what urunler is in the class constructor so that it can't be null:

(A)

```
// ...
if (urunler != null) {
    urunler.setTitle("foo");
}
```

(B)

```
private final Urunler urunler;

public UrunlerHanlder(String qName) {
    urunler = new Urunler();
}
```

Comment: You would use (A) if urunler is allowed to be null by your standards, or (B) if you never want that variable to be null

Comment: I used B one. All of them are null

Comment: Are the values returned null, or is urunler null?

Comment: The values return null

Comment: that would be because by calling an empty constructor (for this particular class), there are no set values within the class, so they will return null until set.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're encountering the `<title>` element under the `<channel>` element before you've encountered an `<item>` element.  Because of that, your `urunler` is still null when you try to call the `setTitle` method on it.

What you should probably do is to check that `urunler` is not null before you try to set that value (as Rogue suggests), since apparently there are `<title>` elements that you're not actually interested in.

Comment: substantially, i am asking this.how can i get nested tags in sax parser.

Comment: The sax parser will get them, but you have to make sure your preconditions are met somehow.  But the accepted answer is the right one for this question.  Use XPath.  It's easier.